# Kivy Script Does not show Labels in Sublime Text

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I am new to Kivy.
When I run the below kivy script on Sublime Text, I get only a Blank Black screen.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

kivy.require("1.10.1")

class LoginScreen(GridLayout):
    def __init_(self, **kwargs):
        super(LoginScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2
        self.add_widget(Label(text="Username :"))
        self.username = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.username)

class SimpleKivy(App):
    def build(self):
    return LoginScreen()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    SimpleKivy().run()
```

Comment: Are you specifying "on Sublime Text" for a particular reason, like it works outside that environment? What does your log say?

Answer (score 0):

The `__init__()` method of `LoginScreen` is spelled incorrectly. It should be:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
```

not:

```
def __init_(self, **kwargs):
```

Note the number of underscores.